# Remote controlling of windows service installed on intranet machine

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, windows-services

I have web application deployed on my local IIS 7, with application pool configured to work under built-in NETWORK SERVICE account. From this web application I need to check the status of my windows service (if it is started, stopped, etc). I've used such statements to get it:

```
public string GetServiceStatus(string machine, string service)
{
    var service = new ServiceController(machine, service);
    service.Refresh();
    return service.Status;
}
```

The `machine` is an IP address of the host in my intranet (let it be 192.168.0.7), where the windows service is running - also under built-in NETWORK SERVICE account.

Unfortunately the code gives an exception:

```
service.Status threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' 
Cannot open MyService service on computer '192.168.0.7'. Access is denied.
```

Where is the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is NETWORK SERVICE doesn't have sufficient rights for controlling windows services. I needed to switch to another user context to be able to control it. But I didn't want to do it for entire application. Instead I was searching for arbitrary piece of code execution under specific identity.

I've checked a lot of resources for impersonation included that shown by Malcolm Frexner. Because I'm working with Windows 7 (64bit) and also with Windows Server 2008 R2 (64bit), that I've found were not working for me. I ended up with such generic solution:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security.Principal;

namespace Thing.Namespace
{
    public enum LogOnType
    {
        LogOn32LogOnInteractive = 2,
        LogOn32LogOnNetwork = 3,
        LogOn32LogOnBatch = 4,
        LogOn32LogOnService = 5,
        LogOn32LogOnUnlock = 7,
        LogOn32LogOnNetworkCleartext = 8,
        LogOn32LogOnNewCredentials = 9
    }

    public enum LogOnProvider
    {
        LogOn32ProviderDefault = 0,
        LogOn32ProviderWinnt35 = 1,
        LogOn32ProviderWinnt40 = 2,
        LogOn32ProviderWinnt50 = 3
    }

    public enum ImpersonationLevel
    {
        SecurityAnonymous = 0,
        SecurityIdentification = 1,
        SecurityImpersonation = 2,
        SecurityDelegation = 3
    }

    public static class IdentityBoss
    {
        private static WindowsImpersonationContext _impersonationContext;
        private static readonly object _locker = new object();

        private static class NativeMethods
        {
            [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
            public static extern int LogonUser(String lpszUserName,
                                               String lpszDomain,
                                               String lpszPassword,
                                               int dwLogonType,
                                               int dwLogonProvider,
                                               ref IntPtr phToken);

            [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
            public static extern int DuplicateToken(IntPtr hToken,
                                                    int impersonationLevel,
                                                    ref IntPtr hNewToken);

            [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
            [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
            public static extern bool RevertToSelf();

            [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
            [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
            public static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);
        }  

        public static void Impersonate(Action action, string user, string domain, string password,
                                       LogOnType logOnType, LogOnProvider logOnProvider,
                                       ImpersonationLevel impersonationLevel)
        {
            try
            {
                ImpersonateValidUser(user, domain, password, logOnType, logOnProvider, impersonationLevel);
                action();
            }
            finally
            {
                UndoImpersonation();
            }
        }

        public static void ImpersonateHappily(Action action, string user, string domain, string password)
        {
            Impersonate(action, user, domain, password, LogOnType.LogOn32LogOnNetworkCleartext,
                        LogOnProvider.LogOn32ProviderDefault, ImpersonationLevel.SecurityImpersonation);
        }

        public static TResult Impersonate<TResult>(Func<TResult> action, string user, string domain, string password,
                                                   LogOnType logOnType, LogOnProvider logOnProvider,
                                                   ImpersonationLevel impersonationLevel)
        {
            try
            {
                ImpersonateValidUser(user, domain, password, logOnType, logOnProvider, impersonationLevel);
                return action();
            }
            finally
            {
                UndoImpersonation();
            }
        }

        public static TResult ImpersonateHappily<TResult>(Func<TResult> action, string user, string domain, string password)
        {
            return Impersonate(action, user, domain, password, LogOnType.LogOn32LogOnNetworkCleartext,
                               LogOnProvider.LogOn32ProviderDefault, ImpersonationLevel.SecurityImpersonation);
        }

        private static void ImpersonateValidUser(String userName, String domain, String password, LogOnType logonType, LogOnProvider logonProvider, ImpersonationLevel impersonationLevel)
        {
            lock (_locker)
            {
                var token = IntPtr.Zero;
                var tokenDuplicate = IntPtr.Zero;
                WindowsIdentity tempWindowsIdentity = null;

                try
                {
                    if (!NativeMethods.RevertToSelf())
                        throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
                    if (NativeMethods.LogonUser(userName, domain, password, (int) logonType, (int) logonProvider,ref token) == 0)
                        throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
                    if (NativeMethods.DuplicateToken(token, (int) impersonationLevel, ref tokenDuplicate) == 0)
                        throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());

                    tempWindowsIdentity = new WindowsIdentity(tokenDuplicate);
                    _impersonationContext = tempWindowsIdentity.Impersonate();
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (token != IntPtr.Zero)
                        NativeMethods.CloseHandle(token);
                    if (tokenDuplicate != IntPtr.Zero)
                        NativeMethods.CloseHandle(tokenDuplicate);
                    if (tempWindowsIdentity != null)
                        tempWindowsIdentity.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }

        private static void UndoImpersonation()
        {
            lock (_locker)
            {
                if (_impersonationContext != null)
                {
                    _impersonationContext.Undo();
                }
            }            
        }
    }
}
```

In addition I needed to create new user on my machine where the service is installed. User has to have permissions for controlling windows services - for that purpose it can be added to Administrators group.

Now I can start / stop my services and getting theirs current statuses in such way:

```
private const string user = "MyUser";  
private const string domain = ".";
private const string password = "MyPa$$w0rd";

public string StartService(string machine, string service)
{
    IdentityBoss.ImpersonateHappily(
        () =>
            {
                Controller.Instance.StartService(machine, service);
            }, user, domain, password
        );
}

public string GetServiceStatus(string machine, string service)
{
    return IdentityBoss.ImpersonateHappily(
        () =>
            {
                return Controller.Instance.GetServiceStatus(machine, service);
            }, user, domain, password
        );
}
```

`ImpersonateHappily` is just a function which takes parameters which are working with my operating system. Other similar solutions from the web used `dwLogonType` parameter passed to win 32 api function `LogonUserA` with values 2 or 9, while under my system value 8 is correct.

BTW: `Impersonate` is a wrapper function which sets up the impersonation and then passes it a lambda which does the actual work. The fancy computer science term for this style of writing code is [higher-order programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_programming).

Comment: This works on my local machine and does not work on the intranet one. It says user/pass combination is not recognized. How is that possible?

Comment: I have no idea what is the source of your problem. Try to give complete stack trace to reveal more info.

Answer (score 0):

Try If you can use impersonation

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306158/en-us