# Powershell WebAdministration from C# web application

Tags: c#, wcf, powershell, impersonation

Im having some issues getting the web administration module to execute commands from a c# webservice that i have created.

```
 InitialSessionState init = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();
    init.ImportPSModule(new[] { "WebAdministration" });
    Runspace r = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(init);
    r.Open();
    System.Management.Automation.RunspaceInvoke invoker = new System.Management.Automation.RunspaceInvoke(r); 
    List<System.Management.Automation.PSObject> result  = invoker.Invoke("get-website").ToList();
```

This fails with the following error **Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))**

if i replace get-website with get-module it returns 1 result - WebAdministration as expected, but no matter what it wont let me access that.
I have tried starting VS as an admin, browser as admin, using the impersonateValidUser.
I've also tried using the following code in wcf

```
WindowsIdentity wi = new WindowsIdentity("administrator@domain.");
    WindowsImpersonationContext ctx = null;
    try
    {
        ctx = wi.Impersonate();
        List<System.Management.Automation.PSObject> result = invoker.Invoke("get-website").ToList();
 }
```

but that also fails with access is denied.

All these tests work fine from powershell when run as administrator.
any suggestions

Comment: It's probably a dead shot but you can play a bit more with the different options of impersonation mechanism. The code which lets you switch to another user execution context for some particular piece of code can be found here (together with some additional details): http://stackoverflow.com/a/14397057/270315

Comment: Check what the ExecutionPolicy is set to inside your program. It can be different than the command line execution of powershell.

Comment: Do you have your C# app manifest setup to requireAdministrator?  This particular module will error on import if it is not running from an elevated process.