# Monitoring Windows service status remotely as non-administrator?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

Background: I have an application that, among other parts of its back-end, uses a server-side Windows service to do some of the computation.

What I'm trying to do is display the status of the service (Running vs. Stopped, essentially) on the client, such that the users can know (a) if the background computation is happening, or (b) if they need to go poke their IT guy to check the server. (It's written for an SME customer that doesn't have a full-time IT department or a budget that wants to be spent on fancy service-monitoring-and-alerting software.)

In itself, that's easy enough to do with ServiceController - *if* you're an administrator on the server, which the users, of course, aren't. Is there a way to read service status from a remote server in .NET as a non-administrative user? (All I need is to read the status; I don't need, and actually specifically don't want, to give the users the rights to stop/restart/alter the service in any way.)

Comment: You might want to look into the [Observer Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee850490.aspx) if you just want the users to know the status. Sample implementation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648108.aspx)

Comment: Consider reporting some perf counter ("computations per second") from your service. Than you'll be able to use any monitoring tool (i.e. starting with built in PerfMon) to see how process is doing... (just general suggestion, does not solve "remote" portion of the question as one still need some permissions to remote lead perf counters).

Comment: Consider using WMI queries to retrieve the service information if the sysadmin is not comfortable with granting access to service control. (Enable Account - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771551.aspx)

Comment: Even I don't want to give the users access to service control!

The WMI solution sounds likely. I'll give it a try and see how it works out.

Comment: Permissions on services are actually quite fine grained. It's possible to configure permissions such that a user is allowed to remotely *query* a (single/specific) service's status without them having permission to start/stop/configure. See [`sc sdset`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc742037.aspx)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thanks muchly, setting up the proper permissions with sc sdset on the service and on scmanager worked perfectly. (If you'd like to turn that comment into an answer, I'll accept it.)

Comment: Happy to help, but it's not a programming answer so I'd feel odd offering it as an answer on here (hence why it was a comment in the first place)

Comment: Rather than try to learn to use `sc sdset`, you can use the SubInACL command-line tool from Microsoft, which has a much simpler syntax.

Answer (score 1):

If the user under which your application works doesn't have sufficient permissions for accessing services, you're likely to get an error like this:

```
service.Status threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' 
Cannot open MyService service on computer '192.168.0.7'. Access is denied.
```

You need to switch to another user context to be able to monitor it. If you don't want to do it for entire application (which is rather obvious), try impersonation for the actual piece of code which does the status checking. What should be the user? Actually for the safety reasons, it definitely shouldn't be the user who has an access for entire machine. It should has access just for controlling the services. Ask the administrator to create such a user for you. The status monitoring can be then executed like this:

```
public string GetServiceStatus(string machine, string service)
{
    return Impersonate(
        () =>
            {
                var service = new ServiceController(machine, service);
                service.Refresh();
                return service.Status;
            }, USER, DOMAIN, PASSWORD
        );    
}
```

The entire thread with detailed solution can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14341234/remote-controlling-of-windows-service-installed-on-intranet-machine).

**Edit:**

Let me explain the topic further. The solution I've provided gives the opportunity to change the user context, for some particular piece of code. It can be whatever you want e.g. service status checking. User, under context such an operation is going to be executed, can have granted the access to perform it, or not. It's completely different story though. It's the computer administrator responsibility to grant such an access. In the simplest case he can just add such a user to the Administrators group, which will be reckless, but he can also grant granular access using Group Policy. More detailed information regarding such an administration issues can be found [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/55961/is-it-possible-to-use-group-policy-to-grant-the-permission-to-manage-windows-ser) and [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/187302/how-do-i-grant-start-stop-restart-permissions-on-a-service-to-an-arbitrary-user).

Comment: I'm not very comfortable with this as a solution, since as I understand it, such a user would be able to control the services, as well as see their status, which is a permission they shouldn't have.  Is there a way to set up such a user to only be able to see service status, but not control it?

Comment: @Cerebrate: You didn't get the point correctly. I've tried to explain it to you further in the edited section of my answer.